# Community ad stats bar isn't hidden

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The stats bar that shows when you hover over community ads should be completely hidden until hovered over, but you can still see half of the bar below the ad:

> [image]

The problem is that the space around the ad is created with `padding` and `overflow: hidden;` only hides content outside of that padding:

> [image]

It would be an easy fix (swap `padding` for `margin`) if it wasn't for the bottom border that creates that faux break in the sidebar. So either the padding needs to be moved to a different element or the border does.

Comment: Will this get status-declined? Lol, It's really annoying and should be fixed

Comment: @WELZ or status-ignored?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure when it happened but this is now fixed.

The footer/stats-bar now has `opacity: 0;` set so that it is hidden until the ad is hovered over:

[image]