# Small CSS error with weekly newsletter ad

Tags: bug, status-planned, advertising

As titled, the weekly newsletter ad is slightly overflowed, not contained in the fixed size ad. I'd guess it's due to a change in margins or something.

I made the background color of the bottom paragraph blue in the screenshot to make the error more obvious, but it's visible without it.

I'm using Chrome for Windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't always see the ad, so it may take some time to to repro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm looks like those may have been that way for a while. I've found the problem, but it doesn't look like a simple fix. I'll get with our design team and see what we can do.

Comment: Is [this](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3339/52050) related? (I can't see the newsletter ad currently so can't see for myself if it's the same problem)

Comment: Yup. Same problem.

Comment: Looks like its fixed now